# Django - use template tags in if statement

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-tagging

I saw similar questions but none of them solved my problem .

I have a simple template tag like this :

```
@register.simple_tag
def liked_by_user(post_id, user):
    try:
        PostModel.objects.get(pk=post_id).like_set.get(user=user)
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

and i want to use this in an if statement like this :

```
{% if liked_by_user post.pk request.user %}
        doing somethin...
    {% else %}
        doing somethin...
{% endif %}
```

what can i do ?

Comment: Return this flag in your post-list queryset.

Comment: @IvanStarostin actually its right , but i want to learn tag filter solution

Comment: Hi Mehdi - is this on a single post page or on a list of posts?

Comment: @MichaelRoberts hi , its a single post

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would set out your template something like this:

```
{% liked_by_user "post_id" "request.user" as liked_by_user_flag %}

{% if liked_by_user_flag %} 
   doing somethin...
{% else %} 
   doing somethin...
{% endif %}
```

However, this *intuitively* doesn't feel like a template tag sort of situation...but I'm not 100% sure of your use case just yet from your question.

Comment: Should have been liked_by_user_flag

Comment: it has template syntax error

Comment: it should be : {% liked_by_user "post_id" "request.user" as liked_by_user_flag %}

{% if liked_by_user_flag %} 
   doing somethin...
{% else %} 
   doing somethin...
{% endif %}

Comment: @Mehdibmp Hi Mehdi - you're quite right, getting my variables mixed up! Apologies, hope the general guidance and solution worked tho.